# Cannot execute Python script via Jenkins

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins

I'm trying to execute a script via Jenkins,but getting the below error.

```
17:11:49 Started by user jenkins_admin
17:11:49 Running as SYSTEM
17:11:49 Building in workspace /Users/it/.jenkins/workspace/pla
17:11:49 [pla] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/t2/sk1vw_mn7mz7ncjw75lzh7r40000gn/T/jenkins414219605931315887.sh
17:11:49 + export PYTHONPATH=:/Users/it/Downloads/
17:11:49 + PYTHONPATH=:/Users/it/Downloads/
17:11:49 + cd /Users/it/Downloads/
17:11:49 + python3 P_execution.py
17:11:49 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'P_execution.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
17:11:49 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
17:11:49 Finished: FAILURE
```

Below is the statement given in JENKINS build section

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/it/Downloads/
cd /Users/it/Downloads/
python3 P_execution.py
```

**Can anyone please let me know how i can resolve it.**

Comment: What user is jenkins running as?  Does that user have permission to read the file `P_execution.py`?

Comment: @JBirdVegas its administrator account which i created during Jenkins installation "Jenkins_admin" , not sure about permission. How can i check it?

Comment: @JBirdVegas Any suggestions please?

Comment: Check if the file is world readable if not make it readable `chmod +r P_execution.py`

Comment: @JBirdVegas Gave the read permission to the file as  mentioned above,but it is having same error.Any suggestions please,have tried many things but none of them is working and i'm not able to figure out what is causing this.Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell export statement has a syntax error. You want this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH:-"/Users/it/Downloads/"}
```

This will use the default `PYTHONPATH` if set, or will set it to `"/Users/it/Downloads/"`.

Comment: Its the same error even after giving this, i think its some permission issue for Jenkins user, but not sure how we can identify it.

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: Verify the file ownership using `ls -l`. If not correct, change it using `chown jenkins_admin:jenkins_admin P_execution.py` or run using the `sudo` command if the user is a part of sudoers.